# Get ID Of Selected Row In Sub Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-forms

I have a Parent Form with a Sub Form and I want the user to be able to select a record from the sub form, then click a button on the Parent Form, which will launch a "new" form that has full demo's pertaining to the selected record from the sub form.

How would I do this in Access 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the ID as a parameter when opening the "new" form.

On your button's `Click` event:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    'Get the ID
    Dim id_ As Long
        id_ = Me.SubformName.Form!ID

    'Open the new form and pass the ID to the .OpenArgs
    DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName", acNormal, , , acFormPropertySettings, acWindowNormal, id_
End Sub
```

On the Form's `Load` event, check the .OpenArgs and filter the form (or whatever else you need to do) to the supplied ID.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    With Me
        If Not IsNull(.OpenArgs) Then
            .Filter = "[ID]=" & .OpenArgs
            .FilterOn = True
            .Caption = "ID: " & .OpenArgs
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```